# Android: Error while generating signed apk : app:transformDexWithDexForRelease

Tags: android, release, signed-apk

The debug build is working as desired.

For below reason i am unable to generate the signed APK.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --output /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/release/0 --min-sdk-version 14 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/6.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/10.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/28.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/37.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/53.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/62.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/29.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/61.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/70.jar
 /Users/bhaskar/Documents/Projects/android-work/familyapp/familyapp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/preDex/release/46.jar
..... trimmed ....

}
```

Comment: Gradle `dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

}`

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.family.app'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled false
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        dexOptions {

            jumboMode true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

        }
    }`